# Set a folder location as a public constant dynamically

Tags: vba

I currently set a public constant in an excel vba module using the code:

```
Public Const QuoteDB = "N:\Data Warehouses\Databases\Quote DB.accdb"
```

The folder location is likely to chance and I would like to be able to enter the location into a cell defined as a range

something like...

```
Public Const QuoteDB = Range("folderlocation") & "Quote DB.accdb"
```

I get an error message when I use this code - any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: "I get an error message when I use this code - any ideas how to resolve this? "  Seriously?  You think we can help you resolve it without you actually telling us what the error message is?

Comment: You canNOT. You can declare a Public variable that you set upfront in your code. You could use VBE programming to add a line in a module but I'm not sure it'll be take into account in the same runtime as VBA is compiled... So in my opinion best way would still be with a Public variable

Comment: roryap, I just asked the question for fun. Of course I'm being serious - other responses were helpful - yours was not!

Comment: He was right, though. Never just write "I get an error message", always include the text of the error message.

Comment: @MatthewBrophy -- My response *was* helpful.  It pointed out something you left out of your question that, if provided, would enable people to answer your question where they really couldn't before, or not without much difficulty.  How else do you define "helpful"?  Don't misconstrue a brusque response as being unhelpful.

Answer (score 1):

The `Const`-Keyword and `Dynamic` contradict each other. You can't assign a dynamic value to a `Const` variable, since this would have to happen at runtime, and that's where `Const` cannot be changed.

Unfortunately, `Public QuoteDB = ...` won't work either.

I suggest you declare your variable as `Public QuoteDB as String`, and write youself a `Sub` or `Function` `init()` in which you assign all values, for example:

```
Sub main()
    call setDirectory()
    ' Variables should be set now

    ' Other stuff:
    call restOfYourCode()
end Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Verzweifler, I tried setting QuoteDB as a public string and created a subroutine that runs automatically when the workbook is opened. So under the object "ThisWorkbook" I put in the following code: Sub setdirectory() 

QuoteDB = Range("DataBaseLink") & "Quote DB.accdb"
RawdataDB = Range("DataBaseLink") & "Rawdata DB.accdb"


End Sub  However, it doesn't seem to set it as a public string.

Comment: When I run other macros in the workbook that use RawDataDb and QuoteDB they are blank when I investigate it in break mode.

Comment: You have to call `setDirectory()` in the same run as the rest of your code, otherwise the variables will reset! See my edited answer for details.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The only problem is my workbook has loads of sheets with lots of buttons that trigger different macros. Is there a way (following your code) to define a public string in this way which can be used by other macros when run separately.

Comment: You could put `setDirectory()` inside all your makros, but doing that in retrospect is cumbersome. Another way of would be writing `Range("folderlocation") & "Quote DB.accdb"` each time you want to use the variable.